# I want to make my headphones set both default playback device and default communication device. How?

Tags: windows, microphone, headset

I have this kind of a situation here. I've received a headset for Christmas because of the online learning due to Covid.

I have these questions:

1. Can I somehow make my headset BOTH default (output) device AND default communication device?
   I want my headset to play whichever audio (game audio, youtube audio etc.)
   But I want it to act as a communication device at the same time - I want it to talk with my friends for ex. on discord, MS Teams--> school etc., but I don't want the sound to come from laptop speakers and let's be honest, I don't want to swap it all the time.
2. Although this headset has a mic, I want this headset mic to work, not that default laptop one and it doesn't show it in the microphone section. It goes along with no. 1 - how can I make it work at the same time?

BTW Windows 8.1 and yeah, I hope there is a different solution because my laptop has only 1 slot for jack mic/headphones.